# Real-time evaluation of a time based rules engine in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, rules

We have a system that uses a Rules engine to determine if a specific label should apply to a User.

For instance:
If checkin_date < today and checkout_date > today then apply label "Checked In"

The rules and labels are stored in MySQL.  We need to get notified whenever a user CHANGES state.  Meaning, they go from "Not checked in" to "Checked in" so we can push a notification out through Node.js.

Is there anyway to achieve this without having to write a cronjob to evaluate all users to see whether a label change has occurred?

Comment: You would need some sort of event to trigger the notification of change. Whether that event is cron, a page load, a web service touching a page doesn't matter. This sort of system doesn't have a way to automatically trigger an event.

Comment: why not put it in the script/class/method that updates your mysql database to signify a status change to begin with?